# newcommand weirdness with optional arguments and `\value`

Tags: macros, counters

In the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{test}
\newcounter{tesp}

\newcommand{\vt}[1]{\value{tes#1}}
\newcommand{\vdt}[1][t]{\value{tes#1}}  % This command with default `t` doesn't work

\begin{document}

\setcounter{test}{1}
\setcounter{tesp}{1}

\addtocounter{test}{\vt{t}}
\addtocounter{tesp}{\vt{p}}

% \addtocounter{test}{\vdt[p]}  % These do not work
% \addtocounter{tesp}{\vdt}

\verb+test+ value: \thetest

\verb+tesp+ value: \thetesp
\end{document}
```

If I uncomment either one of the lines

```
\addtocounter{test}{\vdt[p]}
\addtocounter{tesp}{\vdt}
```

I get `Missing number, treated as zero` errors. I don't understand what I am doing wrong in the definition of `\vdt`, considering the command `\vt` works as expected. How/can I fix this?

Comment: Commands with optional arguments are not (usually) expandable, which means they don't work in `\addtocounter`. You can load `xparse` and do `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\vdt{O{t}m}{\value{test#1}}` and then do `\addtocounter{tesp}{\vdt[p]{}}`, but the extra `{}` is mandatory, so that kind of defeats the purpose of the optional argument. Perhaps `\NewDocumentCommand\addtotest{mO{t}}{\addtocounter{#1}{\value{tes#2}}}` and then use `\addtotest{tesp}` or `\addtotest{tesp}[t]`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik You wanna make this an answer so the question isn't marked as "unanswered" anymore?